# google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 1:1 : Message type "object_detection.protos.TrainEvalPipelineConfig" has no field named "SSD"

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to run *train.py* and I get this error:

> google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 1:1 : Message type
>   "object_detection.protos.TrainEvalPipelineConfig" has no field named
>   "SSD"

Does anyone know how can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly update your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please add # in your firstline becasue there is SSD typed without comment tag (#)

Before

```
SSD with Inception v2 configuration for MSCOCO Dataset.
```

After

```
# SSD with Inception v2 configuration for MSCOCO Dataset.
```